# Saving Dates to a serialized file

Tags: java, date

Im trying to save two dates into a serialized . `bin`  file. I use the  `Calendar class`  to get the current date then I add 30 days onto it. So I try to save two date variables  `fd`  (First Date) and  `ed` (Expiration Date). If I change them to  `Strings`  in the expiration_date_serial file they work, but when I try to save them as  `Date`  they throw errors on these 2 lines:

> exp_date.fd = current_formateddate;
>
> exp_date.ed = formateddate;

**Error:**
incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.Date

**Runnable Class:**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class GetCurrentDate {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get current date
    DateFormat currentdateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");

    Date current_date = new Date();

    String current_formateddate = currentdateFormat.format(current_date);
    System.out.println("Current date:  " + (current_formateddate));

    // ADD 30 days to the current date
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
    Date d = c.getTime();
    String formateddate = dateFormat.format(d);

    System.out.println("+ 30 days: " + formateddate);

    
    // Serialization start
    expiration_date_serial exp_date = new expiration_date_serial();
    exp_date.fd = current_formateddate;
    exp_date.ed = formateddate;

    String fileName = "data.bin";
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(fileName));
        os.writeObject(exp_date);
        os.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Done writing...");

    try {
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                fileName));
        expiration_date_serial p = (expiration_date_serial) is.readObject();
        System.out.println("First Date = " + p.fd +
                " Expiration Date = " + p.ed);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

**Other class:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;


public class expiration_date_serial implements Serializable {
public Date fd;//First Date
public Date ed;//Expiration Date
}
```

Comment: This is just a basic Java programming error. Nothing to do with serialization whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
         .plusDays( 30 )
         .toString()
```

## Details

The [Answer by Orlangure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40207889/642706) is correct, about assigning across types.

Also, other problems include:

- Using old outmoded legacy classes for date-time handling.
- Poor choice of format for serialized date values.
- Incorrectly choosing to use a date-time class for a date-only value.

## java.time

The old date-time classes are poorly-designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them. Now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines textual formats for date-time values. These formats are unambiguous, intuitive across cultures, and practical. The standard format for a date-only value is YYYY-MM-DD such as `2016-10-23`.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 by default when parsing and generating Strings to represent their date-time values.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

### Strings

To generate an ISO 8601 compliant String, simply call `toString`.

```
String output = today.toString();  // 2016-10-23
```

To parse, simply call `parse`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2016-10-23" );
```

### Date math

You can add or subtract amounts of time. Just call the `plus…` and `minus…` methods.

```
LocalDate thirtyDaysAgo = ld.minusDays( 30 );
LocalDate oneMonthAgo = ld.minusMonths( 1 );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

In Java, you cannot assign a value of type String to a field of type Date, that's why the error. It happens even before the serialization.

Your most obvious options are:

- change a type of the field to String
- don't convert Date objects to String and save them as is

You should decide what suits your needs better.